# Iterate Dataframe and format dates when correspond

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have this .csv file

[image]

and I want to take it to a Redshift database in AWS using Glue.

I have this query to map column datatypes from redshift to dataframework datatypes:

```py
query = "SELECT column_name, case when data_type in ('bigint', 'integer') then 'int' when data_type in ('numeric') then 'float64' when data_type like 'double%' then 'float' else 'str' end data_type  FROM information_schema.columns where table_schema='reportes_bi' and table_name='" + tableName.lower() + "';"
```

So, when I iterate the column, it prints this:

```json
{
    "last_name": "str",
    "first_name": "str",
    "identifier": "str",
    "login": "str",
    "fechaprueba": "str"
}
```

Basically, all the values are treated as strings, so the redshift table will only have varchar fields. Now here's the real thing:
I need to iterate the dataframe I got from the csv file, and try to identify the strings that are like-date format and parse them with a specific format, so then I can parse them again as strings and finally insert into the table.
This is the last thing I've tried, it is supossed to iterate each row and analyze its datatype, if it's object (in which dataframe treats strings) it will try to parse the value with the declared format, if it's not, then just pass and continue:

```py
formato = date_format # %Y/%m/%d
    for x in df.columns:
        if df[x].dtypes == object:
            try:
                enm = df.apply(lambda row: row[x].strptime(formato), axis=1)
                print(enm)
                df[x] = str(enm)
            except:
                pass
```

I tried using `.iterrows(), .itertuples(), .iteritems() and .items()` for the iteration, and `df[x].dtypes == str(df[x]), df[x].dtypes == df[x].str.contains('').any()` for the conditionals, but nothing seems to work.
I've readed the docs about iterating dataframes, but in my despair I've been just trying a lot of nonsense mixed options.

**Why not just declare the date columns I want to iterate and parse?**
Because this service creates many and different tables in Redshift with varchars, according to the received csv structure. So it must be capable to identify the date-like format written as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these lines:

```
try:
    enm = df.apply(lambda row: row[x].strptime(formato), axis=1)
    print(enm)
    df[x] = str(enm)
```

To these:

```
try:
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: x.strptime(formato), axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry the late respond. Your answer might be what i need, because now i get an error about incompatible parquet schema. Now i have to adjust some things to solve it.
That said, i'll mark your answer as "the answer". Thx.